# Loading Properties File In JUnit @BeforeClass

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm trying to load sample.properties from my classpath during my JUnit test execution and it can't find the file in the class path.  If I write a Java Main class I'm able to load the file just fine. I'm using the below ant task to execute my JUnit.

```
public class Testing {
 @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {   
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream fileIn = props_.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample.properties");
        **props.load(fileIn);**
    }

}
```

**JUnit:**

```
<path id="compile.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    </path>
    <target name="test" depends="compile">
            <junit haltonfailure="true">
                <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
                <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
                <test name="${test.suite}"/>
            </junit>
        </target>
        <target name="compile">
            <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" 
                   includeantruntime="false"
                   destdir="${build.classes.dir}" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
                <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
            </javac>
            <copy todir="${build.classes.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}/resources"
                         includes="**/*.sql,**/*.properties" />
            </copy>
        </target>
```

**Output:**

```
[junit] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0.104 sec
[junit] 
[junit] Testcase: com.example.tests.Testing took 0 sec
[junit]     Caused an ERROR
[junit] null
[junit] java.lang.NullPointerException
[junit]     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:418)
[junit]     at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:337)
[junit]     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:325)
[junit]     at com.example.tests.Testing.setUpBeforeClass(Testing.java:48)
[junit]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add `${build.classes.dir}` to `compile.classpath`.

**Update**: Based on communication in the comments, it turned out the `classpath` was not the problem.  Instead the wrong class loader was used.

`Class.getResourceAsStream()` looks up the path of the resource based on the class loader the class was loaded by.  As it turns out the `Properties` class was loaded by a different class loader than the `Testing` class, and the resource path was incorrect with relation to that class loader's `classpath`.  The solution was to use `Testing.class.getResourceAsStream(...)` instead of `Properties.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I added the compile.classpath that included the ${build.classes.dir} which resolves to build/classes dir above since it was already like what you suggested, so that isn't my issue unfortunately.

Comment: The only other time this can happen (AFAIK) is when you are trying to load the resource from a class that was loaded by a different class-loader than your own class.  Try `getClass().getReasourceAsStream(...)` instead of `prop.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`.  Let me know if this fixes your problem and I'll update the answer

Comment: InputStream is = Testing.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("sample.properties"); worked, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Please accept it as it now contains the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

`YourTestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`

This **doesn't work**:

`YourTestClass.class.getResourceAsStream`