# Camel Properties Load

Tags: junit, properties, apache-camel

I just read a post discussing loading properties in a Junit

( *[Loading Properties File In JUnit @BeforeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983426/loading-properties-file-in-junit-beforeclass)* )

The properties *load* seems to work but I am not sure how to reference the specific property in my unit test ...any ideas - I am trying to load the value of the ***testinput*** entry in my properties file ?

============================================================
Property file **users.properties** content :

## **testinput**=D/somefolder/somefile

```
public class OrderRouterTest2 extends CamelSpringTestSupport {

  @Override
    protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel- context.xml");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        final InputStream fileIn = OrderRouterTest2.class.getResourceAsStream("/**users.properties**");
        **props.load(fileIn)**;
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendToWebService() throws Exception { 

          // These don't work
          String value1 = context.resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{testinput}}");
          String value2 = "I see ${testinput}";
          String value3 = "I see {{testinput}}";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use useOverridePropertiesWithPropertiesComponent from CamelTestSupport, see: https://camel.apache.org/camel-test.html

Comment: Also, use the file you may already have in your classpath: [Load Property File from Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184488/922457)

Answer (score 0):

Ok ...I tried the obvious ...defining the Property object  outside of the ***before*** class and that worked ...seems like there must another way though to reference that properties object that was loaded in the before class.